# Android : Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-viewbinding

I can't understand why the databinding construct is used .

Why do we need to defraud with this structure when we have to transfer data directly ?

Understanding the view binding structure made sense, but I could not solve the data binding structure, I would be glad if you explain.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of data binding is when the updating of a value occurs at many points in an application code. In this case, you don’t need to keep track of all the ways a value can be updated.

But from a different perspective, data binding may decrease the maintainability of your code. You can read more here: https://quinngil.com/2019/02/05/antipattern-ui-databinding-android/

Comment: So according to what I understand from this article, it allows us to update the value of many view objects from one place, am I correct ?

Comment: Yes. This a one of advantages of Data Binding @Kirion